# Grid Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a 3x3 grid composed of 9 unit squares. Each square can either be Yellow or Blue with equal independent probability. What is the probability that there is at least one 2x2 square containing only Blue squares?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Inclusion Exclusion

Comment: There are 4 ways to choose a 2x2 grid from a 3x3 grid. And for each 2x2 grid with 4 unit squares, there is 0.5 chance that they are Blue. That means for every 2x2 grid, there is a 1/16 chance that all are Blue. 
Therefore, for the entire 3x3 grid we do 4*1/16 = 1/4
But I am not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Cases with at least one 2x2 square:
There are $2^5$ outcomes where the lower right 2x2 is blue.
There are $2^5$ outcomes where the upper right 2x2 is blue.
There are $2^5$ outcomes where the lower left 2x2 is blue.
There are $2^5$ outcomes where the upper left 2x2 is blue.

Cases with at least two 2x2 squares:
There are four pairs of 2x2 squares which leave 3 squares untouched. That is  $4\cdot2^3$ cases.
There are two pairs of 2x2 squares which leave 2 squares untouched. That is  $2\cdot2^2$ cases.

Cases with at least three 2x2 square:
There are four triples of 2x2 squares which leave 1 squares untouched. That is  $4\cdot2^1$ cases.

Cases with at least four 2x2 square:
There is 1 case.

Inclusion/Exclusion gives the number of succesful outcomes:
$(4\cdot 2^5)-(4\cdot 2^3+2\cdot 2^2)+(4\cdot 2^1)-(1)$

Whereas the total number of outcomes is $2^9$.

Probability: $95/512$